# RewriteRules that match inside an Apache Alias or not

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, alias

I have an application that operates in a few different environments, sometimes it's at the top level in a site or sometimes it's operating inside an alias.

When it's a straight checkout to a normal docroot my .htaccess is something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

I deployed the site in an environment that had an alias like the following:

```
Alias /foo /path/to/my/application/
```

I found I had to modify the .htaccess to the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /foo/index.php [NC,L]
```

My question is, how can I rewrite my .htaccess so that the rewriting works the same whether it's under an alias or not? Is there some way I can detect if an alias has been set, or some other way of phrasing the RewriteRules?

Answer (score 2):

Since mod_rewrite takes precedence over mod_alias, you probably need to replace your aliases with rewrite rules.

This:

```
Alias /foo /path/to/my/application/
```

would become:

```
RewriteRule ^foo.*$ path/to/my/application$1 [L]
```

Then the rules in the .htaccess file that may or may not be at the root should work without you having to change them.

Comment: The problem is the site(s) we have are pretty much self-contained separate codebases, that happen to live under aliases of the main site

Comment: Ahh, I see. I'm not sure how you could do it, then. :\

Answer (score -1):

Solution is creating a symlink, if you have access to your document root:

```
ln -s /<path to application> /<document root>/foo
```